# GMail deletes the Body of mails sent from Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, email, smtp

I have the following script in my Unity project, and when I'm sending emails to yahoo or outlook or any other mailing service, there seems to be no issue (except the occasional mail being sent to the spam folder). However, when sending to gmail (and only to gmail) the mail gets sent to the inbox but the entire body of the message gets deleted. What may cause this issue?

The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Threading;
using MimeKit;
using System.IO;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using TMPro;

namespace SendingEmails
{
    public class EmailSenderTEST : MonoBehaviour
    {
        MailMessage msg;
        AlternateView htmlView;
        AlternateView plainView;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client;
        Thread myThread;

        private void Start()
        {
            myThread = new Thread(SendMsg);

            SendMessage();
        }

        public void SendMessage()
        {
            string htmlMessage =
                @"<html>
                <body>
                    
                </body>
            </html>";
            client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587);
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
                SENDER_ADRESS,
                SENDER_PASSWORD);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            msg = new MailMessage(SENDER_ADRESS,
                                                RECEIVER_ADRESS);
            
            htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
                                                            htmlMessage,
                                                            Encoding.UTF8,
                                                            MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
            
            plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
                                                        Regex.Replace(htmlMessage,
                                                                        "<[^>]+?>",
                                                                        string.Empty),
                                                        Encoding.UTF8,
                                                        MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);

            msg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.Subject = " " + "Some subject, testing";
            msg.Body = "Hey this is the email I sent";

            myThread.Start();
            client.Send(msg);
        }

        void SendMsg()
        {
            Debug.Log("Sent");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot when sent to gmail:

[image]

I tried to follow various instructions regarding security and 3rd party apps, but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: Could this be an issue? `string htmlMessage = @"<html> <body> </body></html>";` Are these even required/useful if you just fill those alternative views with an empty body ...? Maybe Gmail is trying to use the html one in particular

Comment: have you checked the raw message content?